# Why is Azure Active Directory Authentication causing an character encoding error in my ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application that I'm making which uses KendoUI as part of its framework.  I recently set up the bones of my application and then, using the built-in wizard of Visual Studio 2019, I added Azure Active Directory Authentication.  This created an app registration for me in Azure that would authenticate users against my company's active directory.

The problem is, when I now run my application, I get the following error and no page loads:

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
>   The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
>   declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
>   mark as an encoding signature.

Further investigation into this message shows more details that are:

> Error loading this URI: Protocol error (unknownError): Could not load
>   the source for https://localhost:44379/. [Exception... "Component
>   returned failure code: 0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED)
>   [nsIInputStream.available]"  nsresult: "0x80470002
>   (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js :: onResponse :: line 555"
>   data: no] Stack:
>   onResponse@resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:555:34
>   onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:123:17 Line: 555,
>   column: 0

I looked at everything that was affected during the addition of AAD and the following files within my project were changed.

- appSettings.json
- Startup.cs
- Extensions (folder)
- `[Authorise]` placed in `HomeController.cs`
- AzureAD (folder)

Having used AAD before in my applications, I expect to see these files changed but I've never had problems with the application running afterward.  I started to investigate what possible change could be causing the problem.  After some work, I realize that, if I remove `[Authorize]` from my controller, everything loads OK.

I'm guessing this is a potential routing issue to my app registration perhaps?  I'm not sure, I need some help as the message is a bit of a red herring as it suggests that there is an HTML formatting issue.  I need some guidance as to what's going wrong.

Here is my code and project structure.

**Structure**

I always separate my UI from my class libraries, since AAD doesn't change files in the Data, Repo or Services libraries I won't include them in this question for brevity.

- MyCompany.Data
- MyCompany.Repo
- MyCompany.Services
- MyCompany.UI

**MyCompany.UI/Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
using MyCompany.Data;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MyCompany.Services;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace MyCompany.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IVesselService _service;

        public HomeController(IVesselService vesselService)
        {
            _service = vesselService;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ReadVessels([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var vessel = _service.GetVessels();
            return Json(vessel.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public ActionResult CreateVessel([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Vessel vessel)
        {
            if (vessel != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.InsertVessel(vessel);
            }

            return Json(new[] { vessel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public ActionResult UpdateVessel([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Vessel vessel)
        {
            if (vessel != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.UpdateVessel(vessel);
            }

            return Json(new[] { vessel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public ActionResult DestroyVessel([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Vessel vessel)
        {
            if (vessel != null)
            {
                _service.DeleteVessel(vessel.Id);
            }

            return Json(new[] { vessel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCompany.UI/Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using MyCompany.Repo;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyCompany.Services;

namespace MyCompany
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
               // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
               // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
               .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

            // Database Context
            services.AddDbContext<MyCompanyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyCompanyConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyCompany.Repo")));

            //Repository Scope
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
            services.AddTransient<IVesselService, VesselService>();

            //Azure AD Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            //Add KendoUI Services to services container
            services.AddKendo();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCompany/appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyCompanyConnection": "Server=tcp:mydatabase.database.windows.net,0000;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Cloud;Password=Midgar1997!;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxx",
    "AppIDURL": "https://mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/MyCompany.UI",
    "ConfigView": "MVC"
  }
}
```

So, that's the code that is directly tied to AAD, I'm not sure if it's a routing issue or maybe, incorrect config of app registration.  I need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce this I can report it as a product bug to the AAD team. Sometimes this error occurs if you are reaching out to a different service (like Azure SQL)and there is an issue with the connection. Do you have further error logs?

If you'd like to make a support ticket feel free to reach out to me at AzCommunity@microsoft.com and I can open a case for you.